# Proving my own expression for sequences of one letter words and two letter words

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, recurrence-relations, proof-explanation

I've created my own expression for representing the sequence of two letter words in the dictionary concatenated with one letter words. There are 2 one letter words and 124 two letter words.

It is: $a_n=2a_{n-1}+124a_{n-2}$

It holds true for my base case which is $a_3$ (words of length three made with concatenated one length word and two length word). The answer is 496.

Now I have to prove that $a_n\le13^n$.

I've done the base case where $a_3=496\le2197=13^3$ so my expression has held true.

Now i'm unsure how to do the inductive step. I know I have to represent $n+1$ to prove it is true for the next numbers but working with the $a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2}$ has confused me.

Is it $a_{n+1}=2a_n+124a_{n-1}+n+1$, am I on the right track? How do I move on from this.

Thanks

Comment: Since you use $A_{n-1}$ *and* $A_{n-2}$, as a start you'll need two base cases, so work out $n=4$ too.
Then, putting $n = k$ you need to show your statement:

$A_k = (A_{k-1} *2) + (A_{k-2} *124)$. You'll have to do this by using the definition of $A_k$ (whatever it may be) and write it in terms $A_{k-1}$ and $A_{k-2}$. I'm not sure if your expression is correct, this is just the way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally (or at least often) in proofs by induction, you show that if the hypothesis is true for $n-1$ then it's true for $n$, do your base case, and that's enough.

Here you can't easily do this, because $a_n$ depends on $a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2}$. So you need the hypothesis to be true for **both** $n-1$ and $n-2$ before you can conclude anything about $n$. This is still a valid type of proof by induction, but you need to check **two** base cases.

In this case, you can show that if the hypothesis is true for $n-1$ and $n-2$, it is true for $n$, because $$a_n=2a_{n-1}+124a_{n-2}\leq 2\times 13^{n-1}+124\times 13^{n-2}=150\times 13^{n-2}<13^n.$$

Comment: Thank you for this! One question though, how did you get 150 x 13^n-2?

Comment: because $2\times 13^{n-1}=2\times 13\times13^{n-2}$.

Comment: Thanks again, but I'm still a little confused, where does the 150 come from?

Comment: $2\times 13^{n-1}+124\times 13^{n-2}=(2\times 13+124)13^{n-2}=150\times 13^{n-2}$. Of course it doesn't matter what the exact number is, so long as it's at most $13^2=169$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, I really appreciate it. Has helped me a lot!